# How do I hide the Google Tag Manager preview pane?

Tags: google-tag-manager, tag-manager

When using the "new" UI (version 2) of Google Tag Manager, I cannot disable the preview/debug pane. It's appearing on every page of my web site whenever I'm logged into my Google Apps account.

I've deleted every cookie from a `*.google.com` domain. As soon as I log back into my Gmail, the Tag Manager preview pane is back.

I've hunted through the Google Tag Manager tool, and I can't seem to find any way to turn off the preview mode. Even publishing the latest version doesn't do the trick.

In the "old" Tag Manager UI, when debug mode was enabled, a callout link would appear atop every GTM page allowing you to Exit debug mode. This does not appear to be possible in the "new" Tag Manager UI.

Comment: Thanks to Stephen Ostermiller for his help. The short answer is: In the GTM UI, click the Container tab at the top of the page. On all sub-pages (Overview, Tags, Triggers, Variables) you should see an orange banner indicating that you're previewing a specific version. Beneath is a "Leave Preview Mode" link.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

From [Previewing and Debugging](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/2695660?hl=en) in the Google Tag Manager help:

> #### Exit preview mode
>
> To exit preview mode from your container, click **Leave Preview Mode**, located in the orange banner on the Workspace Overview page.
>
> For shared previews, use the link received to go to the shared preview landing page. Click on **Exit preview and debug mode** to end your preview session.

[image]

---

**Note**: If you're unable to see the yellow preview section at the top of the Overview page in Google Tag Manager, you may have to disable your browser's ad blocker in order to view this element.

Comment: Make sure you disable any Ghostery type plugins on https://tagmanager.google.com or you won't see the yellow bar in the new UI

Comment: Got caught out with this so thought I would share. Preview mode is account specific. If you and a colleague have both enabled preview mode, them disabling it will not disable it for you.

Comment: you have to open https://tagmanager.google.com to make this changes.

Comment: thanks! it was the ad blocker that was blocking the pop up

Comment: Whoever figured out this adblocker piece, you are a saint!